# Listen to keyboard events in background?

Tags: android

I know how to listen to keyboard events in an activity. But can I do that in a background ? If yes, how to do that?
example i have a plan activity and i want to capture all keyboard event in background and show that in message box.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a keylogger XD Something with a service maybe?

Comment: so you want to know what PIN i am typing in my bank application? no, it does not work that way

Comment: something kinda keylogger. i have qr scanner that is connected to the  app and based on the scan data i want to show the image

Comment: and my app have only pain activity, there is no text box or other controls

Comment: It might be a better idea to make a small gui, which must be active to scan Qr codes. I don't think you can capture all keystrokes. Unless the scanner gives some sort of trigger.